# Will Azure Site Recovery work for VMs that are already hosted in azure

Tags: azure, disaster-recovery

I understand that the ASR is a DR option for on-prem sites. But looks like the workflow is good and fits for the Azure based sites as well. Do you know if there is a way to enable ASR option for the Azure bound VMs? If so can someone explain the steps to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Currently it is not possible. You can only protect virtual machines that are running in an environment away from Azure. You can failover machines from on-prem site and have it running in Azure. You can then use Azure site recovery to migrate/failover to a different site.

Comment: The capability to fail-over of VM's from one Azure region to another region is on the roadmap and possibly will be in public preview in March, 2017